# Include submodules as well in git checkout-index

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is there a way to copy files from the submodules as well when doing `git checkout-index`?

I already checked the documentation of [git checkout-index](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout-index.html) but it makes no mention of submodules

Comment: I don't believe `git checkout-index` is submodule-aware.  Can you use `git submodule foreach` to help you though?

Comment: It seems that it might be the only option.

Answer (score 4):

Neither [`checkout-index.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5a0cc8aca797dbd7d2be3b67458ff880ed45cddf/builtin/checkout-index.c), [`t/t2006-checkout-index-basic.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5a0cc8aca797dbd7d2be3b67458ff880ed45cddf/t/t2006-checkout-index-basic.sh) nor [`Documentation/git-checkout-index.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5a0cc8aca797dbd7d2be3b67458ff880ed45cddf/Documentation/git-checkout-index.txt) mention submodules.
That was confirmed/discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/1009#issuecomment-180842) (2010) or [this one](https://github.com/ansistrano/deploy/issues/33#issue-83606638) (2015-2016).

So (as commented) [`git submodule foreach`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt) remains the best option:

```
 git submodule foreach --recursive 'git checkout-index'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try:

```
#install submodules
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

The recursive flag is not required but, per the [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule):

```
If --recursive is specified, this command will recurse into the registered submodules, and update any nested submodules within.
```